# angular-mock.js conflicts with htmlunit? How to test angular application using angular-mock.js in maven-jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, mocking, htmlunit, jasmine-maven-plugin

I'm new to maven and jasmine, and I have a problem setting up maven to run unit tests on an angular application. I get into trouble as soon as I add **angular-mocks.js** to the test/javascript/lib folder.

`mvn test` throws a `htmlunit.ScriptException` just by adding the angular-mocks file. If I remove the file, it runs just fine (without the parts relying on mocking of course, but they fail as a unit test rather than throwing an error).

Does anyone know what could cause this error and how to fix it?

---

**EDIT**
I stronly suspect that this is a **htmlunit** problem, because the error differs when changing the `<browserVersion>`:

CHROME gives:

> TypeError: Cannot find function attachEvent in object [object
>   HTMLDocument]. (`http://localhost:55408/src/lib/angular.js#1568`)

FIREFOX_3_6 gives:

> Exception invoking Node.removeEventListener() with arguments [String,
>   NativeArray, Boolean]

INTERNET_EXPLORER_9 gives:

> Exception invoking Node.detachEvent() with arguments [String,
>   NativeArray]

---

Stack trace (excerpt FF):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.searls:jasmine-maven-plugin:1.3.1.2:test (default) on project my-jasmine-project: The jasmine-maven-plugin encountered an exception:
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking Node.removeEventListener() with arguments [String, NativeArray, Boolean]
[ERROR] Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c187d01409a5dc3b7f8251859150c8af0bcb', time: '2013-04-09 10:39:28'
[ERROR] System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.4', java.version: '1.6.0_51'
[ERROR] Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
[ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.runner.SpecRunnerExecutor.execute(SpecRunnerExecutor.java:39)
...
```

pom.xml (excerpt):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <preloadSources>
      <source>lib/angular.js</source>
      <!-- <source>lib/angular-mocks.js</source> -->
      <source>http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular-mocks.js</source>
    </preloadSources>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Both adding angular-mocks.js to the test/javascript/lib folder and referencing it directly from the angularjs website give the same error.

Comment: The same tests run fine using Karma (instead of Maven), even when including angular-mocks.js .  So the  problem is almost certainly with Maven or the Jasmine plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the CHROME browser version the error occurs when angular tries to load JQLite a api-compatible subset of the jQuery library that allows angular to manipulate the DOM.  I was able to fix the issue by downloading uncompressed versions of jQuery (v1.10.2), angular (v1.0.7), and angular-mocks (v1.0.7).  I added the following to the configuration in the jasmine-maven-plugin.

```
<preloadSources>
  <preloadSource>${angular-test-deps}/jQuery.js</preloadSource>
  <preloadSource>${angular-test-deps}/angular.js</preloadSource>
  <preloadSource>${angular-test-deps}/angular-mocks.js</preloadSource>
</preloadSources>
```

The angular documentation states that "Real jQuery always takes precedence over jqLite, provided it was loaded before `DOMContentLoaded` event fired" (line 1448 of uncompressed 1.0.7).  This fix still fails with the CHROME browser version but works with FIREFOX_3_6, FIREFOX_17, INTERNET_EXPLORER_9, INTERNET_EXPLORER_8, and INTERNET_EXPLORER_7.  The jasmine-maven-plugin defaults to the FIREFOX_3_6 borwser version so there is no need to specify a browser version.

Comment: This did the trick. It is a better solution than using PhantomJs, which is what I did so far. I used JQuery already in the project so it doesn't even add extra dependencies. Thanks!